# Bug in FFmpeg signature?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-filters

I tried using the signature filter on two completely different videos.

For below command where `video1` and `video2` are completely different videos, the signature filter code still passes the coarse grain check.

It fails the frame level matching but method `get_jaccarddist` always returns true for coarse grain match, which should *not* be the case. This seems to be a bug.

```sh
ffmpeg  -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] signature=nb_inputs=2:detectmode=full:format=xml:filename=sign%d" -map :v -f null -
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This site is [all about questions and answers](https://superuser.com/tour), but your post is just a story. Please [edit] and ask a well-defined question.

Comment: I'll look into this in a while when I have time.

Comment: Thanks Gyan, let me know.